# Pure CSS dropdown menu click to hide or show div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made the following. I want to click on list item to toggle next div.

<kbd>[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zr9km0Lv/7/)</kbd>

When **`click`** on **`list item`**,

```
<li><a href="#">Create/Read/Manipulate</a></li>
```

next **`div.submenu`** display, again click to hide to reflect toggle like effect in jQuery.

```
<div class="submenu"> 
    <a href="#">DOM</a><br /> 
    <a href="#">Reader/Writer</a><br /> 
    <a href="#">SimpleXML</a><br /> 
</div>
```

I do not want to use jQuery. Pure CSS or JavaScript is welcome.

```css
#leftcolumn {
    width: 18%;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 5px 3px 10px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EFF0F1;
    font-size:14px;
    padding: 1px 0px;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li a {
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li a:hover {
    color: #FA7837;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li#activemenu a {
    color: #FA7837;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu .submenu {
    margin: 3px 0 3px 7px;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu .submenu a {
    color: #333;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu .submenu a:hover {
    color: #F9864D;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu .submenu a#activesubmenu {
    color: #F9864D;
}
```

```html
<table id="maintable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td id="leftcolumn" >
      <ul class="leftmenu">   
        <li><a href="#">CDATA</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Create/Read/Manipulate</a></li>
        <div class="submenu"> 
          <a href="#">DOM</a><br /> 
          <a href="#">Reader/Writer</a><br /> 
          <a href="#">SimpleXML</a><br /> 
        </div>
        <li><a href="#">Entity Declaration</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Create/Read/Manipulate</a></li>
        <div class="submenu"> 
          <a href="#">DOM</a><br /> 
          <a href="#">Reader/Writer</a><br /> 
          <a href="#">SimpleXML</a><br /> 
        </div>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The Code Snippet is used for putting the code here, so that even that gets versioned. Do not use jsFiddle.

Comment: You should not use a `div` as direct child of `ul`. Rather keep the `div.submenu` in the submenu's parent `li`.  
Only a `li` should be the direct child of `ul` and `ol`

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT UPDATE QUESTION only minor reason using snippet editor instead of jsfiddle. Is this not a issue. please.

Comment: Okay, I give up @user1153551. Don't worry. I am not editing it.

Comment: You should put the relevant code to the question so that it could stand by itself. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114942/when-jsfiddle-and-other-related-sites-are-gone-so-is-the-information

Comment: @HashemQolami may be is this not possible. jsfiddle is very easy

Comment: minus votes explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found **two** different solution,

**1.)** Use `<input/>` type *checkbox*,

```
li input[id][type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
    top: -1000px;
}
input[id] ~ div[id] {
    display: none;
}
input[id]:checked ~ div[id] {
    display: block;
}
```

#### View demo <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imjaypatel/pydq18jv/)</kbd>

---

**2.)** Open *submenu*, when mouse *hover*,

```
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu a:hover {
  color: #F9864D;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu {
  display: none;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li:hover #submenu {
  display: block;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu a#activesubmenu {
  color: #F9864D;
}
```

#### View demo <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/imjaypatel/ercjn3a0/)</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

You can use hover.

```css
#leftcolumn {
  width: 18%;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 5px 3px 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EFF0F1;
  font-size:14px;
  padding: 1px 0px;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li a {
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li a:hover {
  color: #FA7837;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li#activemenu a {
  color: #FA7837;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu {
  margin: 3px 0 3px 7px;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu a {
  color: #333;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size:14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu a:hover {
  color: #F9864D;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu {
  display: none;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li:hover #submenu {
  display: block;
}
#leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu a#activesubmenu {
  color: #F9864D;
}
```

```html
<table id="maintable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td id="leftcolumn" >
      <ul class="leftmenu">  
        <li><a href="#">Syntax/Rules</a></li>    
        <li><a href="#">Data</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">CDATA</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">Create/Read/Manipulate</a>
          <div id="submenu"> 
            <a href="#">DOM</a><br /> 
            <a href="#">Reader/Writer</a><br /> 
            <a href="#">SimpleXML</a><br /> 
          </div></li>
        <li><a href="#">Entity Declaration</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">How To Write</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I m not able to change my `</li>` element move to end of `</div>` element. pls

Comment: @user1153551 You cannot have a `<div>` directly inside `<ul>`, which is **not a valid** HTML!!!

Comment: @user1153551 Check this out may be http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/zr9km0Lv/4/

Comment: @user1153551 How else you want?

Comment: thank @praveen for your help, i am thing that is is unique so i am change to set class and view my jsfiddle code please make in your posible good way, thanks alot. http://jsfiddle.net/zr9km0Lv/7/

Answer (score 1):

As you specifically mentioned using the 'click' event:

Your corrected HTML (only `<li>` elements are valid children of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` element):

```
<li>
    <input id="demo" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="demo">Create/Read/Manipulate</label>
    <div id="submenu"> <a href="#">DOM</a>

        <br /> <a href="#">Reader/Writer</a>

        <br /> <a href="#">SimpleXML</a>

        <br />
    </div>
</li>
```

And additional CSS:

```
/* to emulate the 'feel' of the other <a> elements: */
label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* move the checkbox outside of the visual field to hide it: */
li input[id][type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
    top: -1000px;
}

/* styling <div> elements with an [id] attribute that are a subsequent
   sibling of an <input> with an [id]: */
input[id] ~ div[id] {
    display: none;
}

/* styling the subsequent sibling <div> element of a :checked <input>
   that has an [id]: */
input[id]:checked ~ div[id] {
    display: block;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zr9km0Lv/3/).

This employs the ability of `<input />` elements, of types `checkbox` and `radio` to preserve a state outside of `:hover` events, and use of the `:checked` pseudo-class to style elements based upon that state.

Bringing the relevant `<div>` element inside of the `<li>` then allowed use of the general-sibling combinator (the `~`) to target that `<div>` based on the state (`:checked`/unchecked) of the checkbox.

Comment: I don't think the OP is able to change the HTML. But nice approach. `:)`

Comment: There's that risk, but I figure he *needs* to change the HTML anyway (invalid HTML is fragile in JavaScript, if for no other reason). And thank you! This is, also, the only way to use a 'click' event to maintain a state/state-change, in pure CSS so far as I know, and you'd already covered the `:hover` approach :)

Comment: Check mine here: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/zr9km0Lv/8/ I just did with your technique. Pure Invalid HTML! `:P`

Comment: I did say 'in JavaScript' ;) But I'm disgusted that HTML is being tolerated at all in CSS :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Check Out this, This is will work. use,
    <li><a href="#" onclick="enableDiv();">Create/Read/Manipulate</a></li>   

                      <style>
                        #leftcolumn {
                        width: 18%;
                        margin: 3px;
                        padding: 0;
                        display: inline;
                    }
                    #leftcolumn ul.leftmenu {
                        list-style: none;
                        text-align: left;
                        margin: 0 5px 3px 10px;
                        padding: 0px;
                    }
                    #leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li {
                        border-bottom: 1px solid #EFF0F1;
                        font-size:14px;
                        padding: 1px 0px;
                    }
                    #leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li a {
                        line-height: 20px;
                        color: #333;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }
                    #leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li a:hover {
                        color: #FA7837;
                    }
                    #leftcolumn ul.leftmenu li#activemenu a {
                        color: #FA7837;
                    }
                    #leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu {
                        margin: 3px 0 3px 7px;
                    }
                    #leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu a {
                        color: #333;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        font-size:14px;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        line-height: 1.3em;
                    }
                    #leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu a:hover {
                        color: #F9864D;
                        text-decoration:underline;
                    }
                    #leftcolumn ul.leftmenu #submenu a#activesubmenu {
                        color: #F9864D;
                    }
                    </style>
                    <script>
                    function enableDiv()
                    {
                         var e = document.getElementById("submenu");
                           if(e.style.display == 'block')
                              e.style.display = 'none';
                           else
                              e.style.display = 'block';
                    }
                    </script>
                    <table id="maintable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                      <tr>
                        <td id="leftcolumn" >
                            <ul class="leftmenu">       
                                            <li><a href="#">Syntax/Rules</a></li>               
                                            <li><a href="#">Data</a></li>   
                                            <li><a href="#">CDATA</a></li>  
                                            <li><a href="#"  
                                           onclick="enableDiv();">Create/Read/Manipulate</a></li>
                                <div id="submenu" style="display:none;"> 
                                    <a href="#">DOM</a><br /> 
                                    <a href="#">Reader/Writer</a><br /> 
                                    <a href="#">SimpleXML</a><br /> 
                                </div>
                                            <li><a href="#">Entity Declaration</a></li> 
                                            <li><a href="#">How To Write</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Do you know what means **Pure CSS**?

Comment: It's ok ay if is this posible either pure css or javascript welcome bt i give most priority on css. but it means not JavaScript not allow.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar you said in your comment
   I do not want use jQuery only CSS or JavaScript are welcome.

Comment: can i get class of this way instead of getElementById()

Comment: @a.saleem Sorry, I removed the downvote. Thanks for the clarification! `:)`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, Fine but please try to Educate person in a way , even he posts wrong answers. Thanks

Comment: Sorry if I have offended you. @a.saleem, my apologies. `:)`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar.. No Problem Dude, No Worries, Don't Apologies, just a conversation :)